# How to reuse class in async Django view

Tags: python, django, oop, async-await, httpx

I've made a class with requests inherited from httpx:

```
class URLRequest:
    """URL request class."""

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = httpx.AsyncClient(follow_redirects=True)

    async def close_session(self):
        """Close session."""
        await self.client.aclose()

    async def get_url(self, url: str):
        """Request url with GET method."""
        try:
            response = await self.client.get(url=url)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return httpx.Response(status_code=500)
```

Somewhere in my views.py:

```
s = URLRequest()  # is that correct to create it here?

async def run(request, url):
    response = await s.get_url(url)
    return render(request, "index.html", context=response.text)
```

I want to use one instance of `httpx.AsyncClient` across many Django views (or maybe there is a better approach) to save hardware resources. So I've made a separate method `close_session`, but I do not understand where I need to call `close_session()`.

I can make it this way and do not bother about closing it myself:

```
async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
    r = await client.get('https://www.example.com/')
```

But creation a new session instance for every request is a bad idea.